# Searching for Blog-Software with Postgres + Maps support

Tags: php, blogging, google-maps

Hy,
I'm searching for a **Weblog-Software** (programming language doesnt matter, PHP is OK) which supports two things:

1. PostgreSQL-Support
2. Maps Integration: I want to show the people where I curently am, so I want to embedd a map (Google Maps oder Open Street Maps) into each blog entry.

I found [seredipity](http://www.s9y.org/) supports PostgreSQL but not the maps (or perhaps I just havent found the plugin)
[WordPress](http://www.wordpress.org) doesn't support (in recent versions) PostgreSQL but [supports](http://web-argument.com/google-map-shortcode-version-11/) Google Maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend, you should look towards Drupal. It has a Google Maps module and supports Postgres natively.

When you get it it can be confusing, you don't need the blogging module turned on unless you have multiple users blogging. You just need to create Story pages to automatically have a front page blog e.t.c.

Good luck with Drupal. It is rewarding eventually

Answer (score 0):

Keep looking at Serendipity, it has several geo-related plugins like GeoTagging your posts  (is that what you want?) and doing hitmaps of users.

I'd also note that while Wordpress has been somewhat anti-postgres in the past, someone has created a postgres plugin, so that might be an option now. See http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/postgresql-for-wordpress/ for details.